# React load page with fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show content of my url /PaisForm inside of div but doenst  work. My code is this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/PaisForm')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        document.querySelector('.Pais').innerHTML = body;
    });
}
```

and this is my div:

```
render() {
     return(

       <div className= "Pais">
       </div>
      );
    }
}
```

When i use console.log in function(body) i can read this:

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
>
> ```
>   You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
>   The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
>
>   To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
>   To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
> ```

Thanks for any help, i dont know if i'm using bad the fetch.

Comment: What is in `PaisForm` file?

Comment: A form with one input created in reactjs too.

Comment: So, your error is likely caused by the way you're rendering the page (server side logic). We'd have to see more of your code to provide a direction to go for that. However, I do want to point out that directly manipulating the DOM the way you are in the componenetDidMount() method is NOT best practice. It would be better to set the value of the body to state and have the body of .Pais be {this.state.body} or whatever state you chose. This way, you could also show a loading indicator or something else to show the user that it's grabbing information elsewhere.

Comment: @Carlos Deseda See my answer, Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to include another component in your react component is like this

First n top of the component

```
import PaisForm from './PaisForm' //path to file
```

Then in the component

```
// your code
<div>
    // use your component
    <PaisForm />
</div>
```

Also make sure you have in your `PaisForm` component

```
export default PaisForm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to doing with load. Something similar load of jquery:   $( ".Pais" ).load( "PaisForm" );

Comment: Can you explain more about what and why you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use a modal and inside the modal show the component. Something like <PaisForm/> but url, because i want to reuse this modal to show all my  forms

Comment: Can you explain how you plan to reuse?

Comment: This is not the way react is intended to use (I'm not even sure if it is possible), the way to use a component withing another component is the way I showed you.

Comment: @CarlosDeseda If you want to reuse this modal, you could pass your `PaisForm`'s component as a props.

Answer (score 1):

*You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.*

This means your browser is not allowed to run any `Javascript`.

To unable `Javascript` on `Chrome` you can do [this](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/chrome) (If you are using another browser then do serach on `Google` how to unable `Javascript` on that particular browser).

---

Another thing is, don't directly manipulate the `DOM` like,

```
document.querySelector('.Pais').innerHTML = body;
```

Instead you can have a variable in state,

```
state={body:''}
```

And you can make use of `setState`,

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/PaisForm')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      this.setState({body});
    });
  }
```

And you can render data from state,

```
<div className= "Pais">
    {this.state.body}
</div>
```

---

**Update**

It seems to be you'r trying to add a component in another component using `fetch`.

FYI [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is only meant for `API` calling.

To actually add a component you need to `import` that component.

```
import PaisForm from "./file_path";
```

and simply add that component wherever you want,

```
<div className= "Pais">
    <PaisForm />
</div>
```